# Error running SSIS package: VSTA designer failed to load

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2005, ssis

When I try to execute a package which uses the Scripting Component object I get the following error:

```
Error: 2011-07-22 09:16:42.25
   Code: 0x00000003
   Source: {Task Name Here}
   Description: There was an exception while loading Script Task from XML: System.ApplicationException: The VSTA designer failed to load:  "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component`enter code here`
```

I am running on a database server that has both SQL2005 and SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1720.0 (X64).

I tried to execute the package using both the 32 and 64 bit versions with the same result.

I originally had an issue on my development machine where the Visual Studio for Applications Designer was not coming up when I tried to use the Scripting Object within an SSIS package for the first time. i resolved this by installing the latest SP for Visual Studio. Obviiously, loading visual Studio is not a possible solution to resolve this issue on a SQL Server.

Sugegstions?

Comment: Is the SSIS package 2005 or 2008? Are you running it using the 2005 or 2008 runtime? Google suggests that you are running a 2005 package with the 2008 runtime.

Comment: It's a 2005 package. I think you got it. Answer it an collect your points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Googling [suggests](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/e8fb528a-37e1-464d-9dc6-a34af6712a1c) you're executing a 2005 package with the 2008 runtime. Assuming that's the case, you can either use the 2005 runtime or upgrade the package.